# как просмотреть xml файл отправленый браузером?

Tags: веб-программирование, post

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь составить `post` запрос. мой браузер при обращении к сайту отправляет post запрос c`xml` файлом. Как можно увидеть его содержимое?

Comment: используйте *Fiddler*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать вкладку `Network` в Хроме. Там вы сможете посмотреть все активности по сети:

1. Жмем `F12`
2. Идем в `Network`
3. Очищаем список запросов перед отправкой:

[image: очистка]

4. Выполняем `POST` запрос (в моем случае я оставляю комментарий к вопросу) и ищу в этом списке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Смотрю `Form Data` - тут все переданные данные в запросе из браузера.